# git svn and rebasing a branch rebases master

Tags: git, svn, branch, rebase

I have a git-svn repository on my local machine.

My workflow was as follows:

```
git checkout master
<made bunch o' changes>
git add .
git checkout -b new_branch
git commit -a
git svn rebase
git checkout master
```

When I checked out master, I was surprised to see the results of the rebase had been applied (minus my changes though).

Is this the expected behavior? I would have thought it would have pulled the latest from SVN into my branch, not master. It was almost as if it did the 'svn rebase' on master first, then rebased my branch with master.

Justin

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this [Git-svn tutorial](http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial):

> You can commit changes to this branch that won't affect your `master` branch, and you can switch back and forth between your local branches and your master branch.
>   In addition, **each of these branches is connected to the trunk of the SVN repository**, so any changes dcommitted from these branches will automagically be merged into the SVN trunk and appear in your local trunk the next time you run `git svn rebase` when you have your `trunk` checked out.

So while your new_branch HEAD is indeed rebased on top on svn changes, said svn changes has been applied to the master branch first, before rebasing `master` and then `new_branch` (since `new_branch` new commits are done on top of `master` new commits).

If is shorter than:

```
(new_branch)$ git checkout master
(master)    $ git svn rebase
(master)    $ git checkout new_branch
(new_branch)$ git rebase master
```